# Haskell Input & Passing Values to Functions

Tags: haskell, io, interactive

```
putStrLn "Enter the Artist Name"
    art <- getLine
putStrLn "Enter the Number of CD's"
    num <- getLine

let test= buyItem currentStockBase art num
    printListIO (showcurrentList test)
```

the values i have to pass for buyItem is

```
buyItem currentStockBase "Akon" 20
```

but i want to send "Akon" to art and for 20 i want to send num

it gives me this error

```
ERROR file:.\Project2.hs:126 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : buyItem currentStockBase art num
*** Term           : num
*** Type           : [Char]
*** Does not match : Int
```

please help me

Comment: Do yourself a favor and look at http://book.realworldhaskell.org/ and http://learnyouahaskell.com/.  I bet it won't be as frustrating as getting stuck all the time and waiting for answers here.

Answer (score 5):

`num` is a `String`. `buyItem` is expecting an `Int`. You need to convert the String into an Int, for example by using `read`.

```
buyItem currentStockBase art (read num)
```

Edit: `String` means `[Char]` --- hopefully this means the error message makes more sense to you now.

Answer (score 2):

Is it because num is a string? Try parsing it with `read`:

```
let test= buyItem currentStockBase art (read num)
```